# Что за игра "тавлеи"?

Tags: терминология

Простите сразу, если вопрос неподходящий — тогда давайте его перенесём куда лучше.

В фильме "Садко" султан говорит: "Сыграем в **тавлеи** золотые". А потом кто-то нашёптывает Садку: "Отдай слона", то есть получается, что они играют в шахматы. А в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8) говорится, что это русский вариант нардов.

*Что же всё-таки такое *"тавлеи"* на самом деле или ими могут называться разные игры?*

Comment: Точно! Даже не дочитал до этого тогда. Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

На эту тему целые научные изыскания есть. Вот например: http://russia.weiqi.ru/2007/08/29/31/ Я прочитала с интересом, много нового узнала.

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/pepelats/drevniaia-igra-tavlei-pravila-igry-5eed2a640c54162f7f45f406 - здесь даже правила игры есть, оказывается, в древние игры и сейчас играют.

https://tesera.ru/article/iik9/  - тоже интересно.

> Тавлеи (предп. от лат. Tabule — доска) — игра, близкая к шахматам и
> шашкам, распространённая на Руси в 6 в. до н.э. — 12 в. н. э. Правила
> утрачены в период средневекового церковного запрета на игры. При Петре
> I тавлеями назывались шашки.
>
> Никому не известно, какими были древнерусские тавлеи. Но точно
> известны некоторые их черты: возможность строить трёхмерные фигуры
> (кстати, кажется, это уникальная черта исключительно русских игр);
> игра на доске; разные фигуры; возможность играть тавлеями в шахматы
> (но не наоборот); возможность закрывать ход («недоступить-переступить»
> можно трактовать, как неудачные ходы).  Есть такая игра! Видимо,
> кто-то десять лет назад прошёл сходным с моими размышлениями путём и
> решился реконструировать правила на том небогатом известном материале.
> В результате появились русские шахматы или таврели. А вот теперь
> смотрим, какая интересная картинка получается. Шахматы в Индии
> появились где-то на рубеже 6-7 веков нашей эры. Чатуранга, которую
> считают их предшественницей — не ранее 5 века н.э. Ладно, написанное в
> начале, что в тавлеи на Руси играли в 6 веке до нашей эры — это
> гипотеза одного из исследователей (Кадников Е.А., «Шашечные
> арабески»). Но как было сказано — в раскопках около Рязани найдены
> тавлеи 4 века нашей эры. Так что, как бы неловко я себя не чувствовал,
> но я вынужден сказать: «Русский лучник — старший брат индийского
> слона!». Ну и т.д.: ратник — пешки, всадник — коня, волхв — короля,
> князь — ферзя...

А в Садко прямо говорится: *"Доски шахматны со тавлеями, А тавлеи-то чиста золота, Словно жар..."*

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Comment: "распространённая на Руси в 6 в. до н.э.". Я тоже много нового узнал, учитывая что первое упоминание "Руси" датируется 9 веком.

Comment: *как бы неловко я себя не чувствовал,* - что-то тут не так...

Comment: Я скопировала отрывки автора, не исправляя ошибки. Даты  у него тоже под вопросом, но он же сказал, что это чьи-то гипотезы, а на РЕН ТВ гипотезы ещё фантастичнее. Может, речь идёт не о государстве Русь, а о территориях славян, где потом оно образовалось. Интересна сама мысль о связи индийских и русских шахмат, о том, что русские шахматы старше по возрасту. Интересна и связь лучник - слон - офицер. А "много нового узнала" относится к другой статье - к первой, от болгарского исследователя.

Comment: Если события "Садко" - 12 век,  о шахматах там  говорится как об уже известной игре, и называется уже именно шахматами, может, и верно, что появились они гораздо раньше и назывались по-другому, и вид был другой. Почему нет?